# Convert DATETIME with YY to DATE with YYYY in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I want to convert a Timestamp field into Date.
It currently has the following format:

Tms_field= 31-JAN-21 12.00.00.000000000 AM

I want it to be:

31-JAN-2021

I've tried the following

`select to_date(to_char(Tms_field,'dd-mon-yyyy')) from my_table`

But it returns

31-JAN-21

How can I fix it?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Add 2 millenia to the date.  It was stored incorrectly.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It is probably just that the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` is set to `DD-MON-RR HH12:MI:SS.FF9 AM` and the century is hidden rather than being set to the incorrect century.

Comment: @MT0 . . . That is a possibility that has occurred in the past few years.  It was much more obvious . . . once upon a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `TIMESTAMP` column is a binary data type consisting of 7 to 20 bytes (1 byte each for century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second then up to 6 bytes for fractional seconds and 7 bytes if there is any time zone information). It does **NOT** have a format.

What you are seeing is the client program displaying the `TIMESTAMP` in a manner that you the user would find more useful so you need to change this display format or else apply a format to the `TIMESTAMP` column by converting it to a string.

So, if you want to display a `TIMESTAMP` in the `dd-mon-yyyy` format then use `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR( tms_field, 'dd-mon-yyyy' ) FROM my_table;
```

If you want to change how the user interface displays all `TIMESTAMP` values and you are using SQL/Plus or SQL Developer then you can use:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'dd-mon-yyyy';

SELECT tms_field FROM my_table;
```

*(Note: this does not affect the values in the database, it is purely for formatting in the user interface.)*

*(Note 2: you will probably find that your current `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` is `DD-MON-RR HH12:MI:SS.FF9 AM` which is why it is not displaying the century.)

If you are using a different user interface then you will need to check the user guide for that UI.

If you want to convert the `TIMESTAMP` to a `DATE` then just use `CAST`:

```sql
SELECT CAST( tms_field AS DATE ) FROM my_table;
```

However, a `DATE` is also a binary format that always has century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second components and also does **NOT** have a format.

It may be displayed by the user interface you are using without the time component but it will still be there in the background. You can change the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter to change the default display format for SQL/Plus and SQL Developer if you want to change how all `DATE` values are displayed.